# update entity in azure functionV2 use node.js

Tags: node.js, azure

I tried to use this code tu update my existing entity
(https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2311)
, but didn't function. The code is getting same error: The specified entity already exists. Can you help me? I would like to use bindings on this simply code.I read many questions for this problem, but didn't find correct answer

here is .json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "tabledbc",
      "tableName": "dbc",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

here is .js

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.bindings.tabledbc = [];
    const existingTable = context.bindings.tabledbc;
const updatedTable = Object.assign(existingTable,{
    __etag: "*",
    etag: "*",
    ETag: "*"
  });

  context.log("updated org:", updatedTable);

  context.bindings.updatedTable = updatedTable;

        context.bindings.updatedTable.push({
            PartitionKey: "Test",
            RowKey: "test3",
            Name: "test"
        });
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now the table binding doesn't support update the table, in the [output doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#output) and [the github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/919#issuecomment-525325621) confirm it also said it doesn't work for node for now.

In the official doc also point use the storage sdk to do the replace action, so the below is my code.

Use this dependency in the package.json.

```
"azure-storage": "^2.0.0"
```

index.js:

```
let azure = require('azure-storage');
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    let person = {
        PartitionKey: 'test',
        RowKey: 'test',
        name:'testvalue'
    };//thi is new entity

    let connectionString = process.env.AzureWebJobsStorage;
    let tableService = azure.createTableService(connectionString);
    tableService.insertOrReplaceEntity('Person', person, (error, response) => {
        let res = {
            statusCode: error ? 400 : 204,
            body: null
        };
        context.done(null, res);
    });   
};
```

Comment: one question. what is this command do?tableService.insertOrReplaceEntity('Person', person, (error, response)

Comment: @Jan Perdok,Inserts or updates a new entity into a table.